# Typos is a book. Probability

Tags: probability

On the first 400 pages of a book, you notice that there are, on average, 10 typos per page. What is the probability that there will be at least 3 typos on page 401? Think about what assumptions you should be making.

I know that the expected value is 10. Do i need to use a normal Approximation or Poisson to try and answer this problem. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you meant "Typos *in* a book," haha.

You should use the Poisson distribution.  The Poisson distribution is appropriate when there are a fixed large number of trials in a given interval (a page, in this case) and each trial has a fixed (usually low) probability.  The product of the number of trials and the probability of success (or typo) in each trial is the *rate* $\lambda$ of the Poisson distribution.

ETA: In the limit, as $\lambda$ increases without bound, the distribution does approach a normal distribution.  At $\lambda = 10$, here, the difference is not profound, but it's still more appropriate to use the Poisson distribution.

In actual fact, since the number of characters on a page (i.e., the number of trials on a page) is finite, it might be even more appropriate to use a binomial distribution.  However, the difference between the binomial distribution and the Poisson distribution is not significant at this scale, and the Poisson distribution is far easier to compute.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like they want you to assume the distribution of typos per page is Poisson process. Specifically, a Poisson process with mean $10$, with units of typos-per-page. This is reasonable if one assumes that the waiting time between typos is independent of other times and a typo has an equal probability of occurring anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The information you are given is the average rate of occurrence of errors per page. Therefore a Poisson distribution is appropriate. You will need to state clearly the assumptions that you are making. You should be able to find quite early what the usual assumptions are for a Poisson distribution to be a good model. The parameter for the Poisson distribution is indeed 10.

Comment: So would i just do sum the poisson distribution from 0 to 3?

Comment: Sum from 0 to 2. Subtract this from 1 to get the probability of at least 3.

Comment: @Jacob: No.  You would sum the Poisson distribution from $3$ to $\infty$.  (Equivalently, and less infinitely, you would sum the Poisson distribution from $0$ to $2$, then subtract the result from $1$.)

Comment: okay perfect thank you

Comment: @BrianTung I see we are typing equivalent replies simultaneously. Great minds think alike!